# <table> child elements usage in shadow dom

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there any constraint that's preventing `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>` and so on to be slotted in shadow DOM?

Given the following example:

```
<script>
class Table extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <slot name="header"></slot>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <slot name="row"></slot>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        `;
    }
}
window.customElements.define('data-table', Table);
</script>
<data-table>
    <tr slot="header">
        <th>header1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr slot="row">
        <td>cell1</tr>
    </tr>
</data-table>
```

renders into the following structure:
[image]

The workaround would be to use templates and insert template content with JS in `slotchange` event handler, but I would like to avoid that since the cloned content would end up in shadow DOM and it will not be possible to override styles from outside of the custom element.

Comment: ``<tr>`` requires a ``<table>`` parent. So in this use case better parse the lightDOM and inject them in the table

Comment: That's not related to the shadow DOM. `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` only allow `<tr>`s as child elements.

Comment: unfortunately, @Andreas is right, https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#the-table-element - table does not allow `<slot>` as its child or a child of any of its descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment this is currently not possible according to Custom Elements spec v1.
The spec limits tags of `<table>` to a set of `<tbody>`, `<thead>` and so on plus `<script>` and `<template>`.
Browser vendors are reluctant to incorporating changes in their HTML parser https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/59.
Guess the only solution for now is to use a mesh of `div`s with a bunch of `aria-*` attributes.

Comment: Yes, issue was raked up today:https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6226 also, but see Anne his answer, they are not going to mess with the parser. As I said in the comments above, you can move those ``TR`` from lightDOM to shadowDOM yourself: ``this.shadowRoot.querySelector("TBODY").append(...[this.querySelectorAll("TR")])``

Comment: I'm building a library that consumes such elements, I am not able to inject such things into my shadow DOM nor am I willing to do that with JS, thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0):

**put other tags on the `table` it's not correct**  then you should use `css prop` ( `display: table-cell;`, `display: table-row`, `display: table-header-group;`, `display: table-footer-group;`) with other tags.

But if you still want to use the `table`,

you can append tag with function as follow:

[lit playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-YDtcbiAgfVxufVxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxoZWFkPlxuICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy5qc1wiPjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPC9oZWFkPlxuPGJvZHk-XG4gIDxkYXRhLXRhYmxlPjxwPlRlc3QgcCBpbiB0YWJsZTxwPjwvZGF0YS10YWJsZT5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9XQ)

```js
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('data-table')
export class dataTable extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
      table {
       border:1px solid;
      }
  `;
  render() {
    return html`
     <table>
        ${this.templateGen()}
     </table>
    `;
  }
  
  
  templateGen() {
   return html`<slot></slot>`;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="module" src="./simple-greeting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <data-table><p>Test slot in table<p></data-table>
</body>
```